# Beta Decay in Time Dependent Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, radiation, perturbation-theory, time-evolution

I'm trying to find the probability of an electron jumping from the 1s to the 2s state due to Beta decay, where $Z\rightarrow Z\pm1$.

My idea is that $H' = -\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{(Z\pm1)e^2}{r}$, $E_1=-\frac{Z^2e^2}{2a_0}$, and $E_2=\frac{(Z^2+1\pm2Z)e^2}{8a_0}$.

If this is correct, I'm not sure how to get $H_{12}'$. Shouldn't there be some time dependence?

Comment: The time dependence is trivial, the change from the original to the new Hamiltonian happens so fast that to a first approximation the wavefunction does not change. This means that the electron will remain in the 1s eigenfunction of the old Hamiltonian after the decay. But, of course, that old 1s eigenfunction is no longer an eigenstate of the new Hamiltonian, so all you need to do is compute the overlap between the old 1s state and the new 2s state.

Comment: So I need to find $<\Psi_1|\Psi_2>$? I'm also not sure what those wavefunctions would be for a generalized atom.

Comment: Yes, so you have to write down the 2s eigenstate of the new Hamiltonian and compute the inner product with the 1s eigenstate of the old Hamiltonian. These eigenfunctions depend on Z and since Z has changed, the two states are not orthogonal.

Comment: But are the 1s and 2s eigenstates the eigenstates of the Hydrogen atom with the new $Z$? That's what I'm not sure of. I've never really done something with a general atom like this.

Comment: You take $\left|\psi_1\right>$ to be the 1s eigenstate of the old Hamiltonian, because after the beta decay the electron will still be in that state. You want to find the probability of this being detected in the 2s state of the new Hamiltonian, so you take $\left|\psi_2\right>$ to be the 2s state of the new Hamiltonian and then compute the inner product.